# correct sql query

Tags: plugins, query, sql

I wrote database queries some time ago and now I would like to improve them.

But something I do wrong and i need help.

```
    class tags{

       private $wpdb;

      public function __construct(){

         global $wpdb; 
         global $table; 

        $this->wpdb = $wpdb; 

        $table = 'tags'; 
        $this->table_tags = $table;


         }


        public function some(){

        // If I delete the value after the decimal point then it does not work. Is correct query and what use this query witch "WHERE"?

    $how_much = $this->wpdb->get_var($this->wpdb->prepare("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `".$this->table_tags."`", $this->table_tags));           

        }

        public function some2(){

           //here i need display some, work but I do this correct?

          $tags = $this->wpdb->get_results($this->wpdb->prepare("SELECT * FROM `".$this->table_tags."` ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT %d, %d", $from, $in_site), ARRAY_A);


        }

        public function some3(){

        // here i want add some, work too

      $data  = array( 'name' => $name );

      $data2 = '%s';

      $this->wpdb->query($this->wpdb->prepare(" INSERT INTO `".$this->table_tags."` (`name`) VALUES (".$data2.") ", $data ));


        }


    public function other(){

          // is correct? delete


              $this->wpdb->delete($this->table_tags, array('id' => $id));

         // and update

              $this->wpdb->update( $this->table_tags, array( 'name' => $name ), array( 'id' => $id )); 


   }

}
```

And here question.

In `$wpdb->delete` and `$wpdb->update` it is not used `prepare()` and `query()` ?

Comment: I should use prepare() to all database operations ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use [`prepare`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wpdb/prepare/) only when you're using SQL query - this function takes query and params and returns a safe SQL query filled with given params.

Its result is a SQL query. So you can (and should) use it whenever you're creating a SQL query and put some params in it.

With `$wpdb->delete` or `$wpdb->update` you don't create any string containing SQL query - both these functions are taking only params and the create and run the queries for you - so there is no need for preparing.

If you use `$wpdb->insert`, then you also don't have to prepare - there is nothing to be prepared.

But if you insert with raw SQL, as you do in your code, then yes - you should always prepare such query.

Comment: I always use   `$name= trim(sanitize_text_field($_POST['name']));`

Comment: I still must use prepare always?

Comment: sanitize_text_field (https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/sanitize_text_field/) is not a solution - it doesn’t make given string sagę for DB queries. So if you’re usune it for escaping DB queries, then you use it incorrectly.

Comment: I use it alwyas before run query, prepare values for query

Comment: @polyman so you’re doing it incorrectly and misuse this function - it does not escape values and does not prepare them for use in SQL queries (for example it doesn’t do anything with quotes; and it’s not meant to). On the other hand it does some things that not always are necessary (for example it strips tags and line breaks).

Comment: Is some tutorial / thread about this?